# ISP Notice Regarding Infected Computer and Potential Disconnection

Tags: networking, router, virus, malware, anti-virus

Recently, my parents received an email supposedly from the ISP (Internet Service Provider) stating that their computer is infected and if they don't take steps to clean it, they may face disconnection from the internet.

The email seemed legitimate, but my parents are a bit concerned and unsure about how to address this situation. I ask if they have been experiencing certain issues on their computer, such as slowness and unusual pop-up windows, which could support the ISP's claims, they do not think so.

I would like to request your help and advice in this matter. What steps should we take to ensure the computer is clean from any infections and prevent any further issues with the ISP? What antivirus programs or cleaning tools would you recommend? I'm also interested to know if these kinds of messages from the ISP are common and if anyone else has had similar experiences.

I appreciate any guidance or advice you can provide.

Comment: Look at the headers and see if the email is true. I get many emails that my credit cards, bank accounts and so on have been cut off. I dump such emails.

Comment: Hello, sounds like very obvious scam, ISP would never contact anyone about this under normal circumstances. If there are any attachments or links that download files, they should **abolutely not** touch them until someone makes sure the email is secure for them, e.g. they could call the ISP if there's noone nearby that could help. Similarly, they shouldn't log in into any account through any links. Should have been asked at https://security.stackexchange.com BTW.

Comment: @Destroy666 It could be a scam but it could also be legitimate.  An ISP should absolutely contact a client if bad traffic is originating from their IP's.   The correct steps are to independently verify this with the ISP by calling them (from a number you obtain independently of the email).

Comment: @davidgo contact - maybe. Not realistic in my country, but in USA it's more possible. Immediately threaten with internet disconnection - no, just no. Of course it's still possible, because companies can be terrible, but the likelihood that this is not a scam is extremely low, as this is a commonly used and known scammer tactic.

Comment: You can both check the computer for malware and clean it, using the software on the computer and the various reputable guides online and on this site, AND consider it is likely the email may be false and a scam attempt. The links and instructions in the email, what they are asking you to do, is the best way to tell whether the email is a scam. And it is never a bad idea to make sure that your security software is working properly and that your computer is clean.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a [standard scam](https://www.enigmasoftware.com/fake-windows-support-calls-infect-computer-users-malware/), **Fake Windows Support Calls Seek to Scam and Infect Computer Users with Malware**. You can also show them [this article from AARP](https://www.aarp.org/money/scams-fraud/info-2019/tech-support.html) to reinforce the point.

However, it is not impossible that there *is* malware on their PC, perhaps disrupting the internet by participating in a distributed [denial of service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) (DDOS) attack.

- **Do not use any suggestions in the email to check for malware!**.
- **Call the ISP at a valid phone number (not one in the email) and/or email the ISP at a valid email address** (not that in the message). **Do not reply to the warning email.**
- Use any reputable malware scanner, such as [free Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/malwarebytes-anti-malware/) for a *single scan*.

A windows PC should *always* have a functioning anti-malware suite, such as Windows OS built-in *Defender*.

- If one is not running on that PC, fix that. IMHO, free suites such as Defender work as well or better than paid services.
- Do *not* use more than one malware suite at a time, except for the *single-scan* mode suggested above -- they just get in each others' way.
- Before installing any application, whether anti-malware or other, scan it at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload). A single warning out of 50 might be ignored, but use caution when installing software.

Comment: Except this was not a phonecall and ISP's do sometimes notify clients of these kinds of things.    **I Agree with your adivce not to use suggestions in the email to check for malware** but the first step is independently checking if the email is legit with the ISP.  (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/216300/received-email-from-isp-saying-one-of-my-devices-has-malware  is on point here)